# "While loop" not working in my Anylogic model

Tags: anylogic

I have the model which I posted before on Stack. I am currently running the iterations through 5 Flow Chart blocks contain enter block and service block. when agent fill service block 5 in flow chart 5, the exit block should start to fill block one and so on. I have used While infinite loop to loop between the five flow chart blocks but it isn't working.

```
while(true)
{
  for (Curing_Drying currProcess : collection) {

    if (currProcess.allowedDay == (int)time(DAY)) {
       currProcess.enter.take(agent);        
         }   
}
if (queue10.size() <= Throughtput1){
  break;
}
```

}

[Image for further illustration 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ov5Ny.png)
[Image for further illustration 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f613N.png)
Wondering if someone can tell me what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve (always explain clearly what your goal is), we have no idea what you mean by "station", etc. Anyway, that code is very bad practice. If the first `if` isn't met, you are stuck in an infinite loop. Also, the whole code is not a good idea, tbh...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description and the pictures provided, it isn't clear why the *while* loop is necessary. The `On exit` action is executed for each Agent arrival to the **Exit** block. It seems that the intention is to find the appropriate **Curing_Drying** block based on number of days since the model start time? If so, then just iterating through the `collection` is enough.

Also, it is generally a good practice to provide more meaningful names to collections. Using simply `collection` doesn't say anything about the contents and can get pretty confusing later on.